Does the philosophy of data analysis exist?
Is there such a field as "philosophy of data analysis"?
Questions that are of interest to me are

What are the distinctive features of data analysis as opposed to other elements of scientific methodology?

Examples of data analysis yielding bad/suboptimal results are relatively easy to think of. Is there such a thing as a data analysis which finds the truth behind the data?


EDIT: Both an answer to the question in title, and your opinions on the specific questions of interest to me are good.

Obviously yes; today we have philosophies for everyting...

Maybe useful: Wolfgang Pietsch, On the Epistemology of Data Science: Conceptual Tools for a New Inductivism (2022, Springer) and Luciano Floridi & Mariarosaria Taddeo, What is data ethics (2016)

The short answer is no (@MauroALLEGRANZA : today we have everything and the contrary of everything, and rather the end of philosophy...).  Answering those questions is up to the theory and discipline (the field of study and its results) itself: defining its own scope (boundaries), terms, and motivations.  That indeed is what a Theory is ("theory" here not in the formal sense but in its proper sense).

It is an emerging field, just like data science itself. For a survey of literature see SEP, Scientific Research and Big Data, especially sections 5 (data as evidence for truth) and 10 (distinctive features of data-centric science).

@Conifold I didn't mean we can't talk about it, but I am being drastic: "philosophy of" is properly about the boundaries of a discipline and the pre-theoretic motivations, and philosophy proper rather says just that. Plus (IMO), a "philosophy of data science" remains at best improper, the relevant problems already belong to their appropriate categories, though, again, a philosophy/er could surely say that much...
